# WPF - Display Items Control inline with parent content

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface

I am tring to create a layout in wpf that will display a parent class Name and then a list of attributes associated to the parent class.  I am using the parent as the root DataContext and then binding an ItemsControl to the child list of Attributes.

I would like the display to be something like below so that when the line wraps it will display the next Attribute under the title "ParentName - "

ParentName - Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3
Attribute4, Attribute5 and Attribute6

My problem is I can not figure out how to make "ParentName" run inline with the attributes so it always comes out with the following line indented to match the first Attribute horizontally, not the "ParentName -" component as I would wish.

Are there any containers that allow such a thing?  It seems like all avaailable containers are like HTML block elements.  I would very much like to do this through XAML and not code behind.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemDisplay">
    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="3">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    <ItemsControl Name="ToppingModificationsItemControl" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemAttributes}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding AttributeName}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                 </WrapPanel>
             </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
   </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I can't include the actual code I'm working on, but I'm hoping the above example will illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish.  For the item being rendered you could assume a class with a String property for Description and a collection of Strings in a property called Item Attributes.

Would like to see

```
ItemDescription - Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3
Attribute4, Attribute5
```

not

```
ItemDescription - Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3
                  Attribute4, Attribute5
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: I added an example, I'm hoping my edits didn't mess up anything beyond recognition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with basic XAML.

WPF Panels are kind of block like, and I don't think there's any that would support an `__|` shaped block like you want for your `ItemsPanel`, that would wrap around another object in the top left corner.

I would just use an `IValueConverter`, and have it convert your data object to a string in the format you want.

Something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyObjectToDisplayValue}" 
           TextWrapping="Wrap" ... />
```

Where your converter does something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(val.Description);

if (val.Attributes != null && val.Attributes.Count > 0)
{
    sb.Append(" - ");
    foreach(var a in val.ItemAttributes)
        sb.Append(a.AttributeName + ", ");
}

return sb.ToString().TrimEnd(", ");
```

Of course, if you can do that as a property of your data object it would probably be even better, but if it doesn't make sense than a `Converter` would probably be the next best thing.

Comment: Agreed.  That was my backup solution as well.  Maybe it's just the app I'm working on but I seem to keep running into this often and is something I could do in HTML, so was hoping I was just missing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to get 2 columns. In this case I'd replace the outer WrapPanel with a Grid or a horizontal StackPanel.

Comment: I think that is backwards.  I want it to work as if everything was in a single wrap panel.  The second example is what I DONT want and can get this quite easily.  It looks pretty similar with either a Grid or a Wrap Panel in that element.  With the Grid it just puts the Item Description in it's own column.  With a WrapPanel then I have two items, the description and the inner wrap panel which then go side by side.  I need an html style inline treatment or something that can immidate that in look.  But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to this issue was to create a single interface for the two collections and then bind to a property that would return the results for both lists.  Then setup the templates to be selected implicitly by type.  By only doing a single bind statement I was able to put all content into a single wrap panel.